# Read a matrix from a file in Scala Breeze

Tags: scala, scalala, scala-breeze

I want to read a tab-delimited text file into a Breeze DenseMatrix.  I see in the ScalaDoc that this should be possible and there are a whole set of I/O classes, but I can't find any examples and it's hard to digest the ScalaDoc.

Can someone provide a simple read/write example?

Answer (score 5):

There's a way to read a csv file into densematrix

```
import breeze.linalg._
import java.io._
val matrix=csvread(new File("your file localtion"),',')
```

api:http://www.scalanlp.org/api/breeze/index.html#breeze.linalg.package

Comment: scala is a case-sensitive language, the "file" should  be "File". "val matrix=csvread(new File("your file localtion"),'$seperator')"

Answer (score 3):

You can use `scala.io.Source` to read in tab delimited data from file.

Some sample data:

```
0       1       2       3       4       5
6       7       8       9       10      11
```

One of the `DenseMatrix` constructors has this form `new DenseMatrix(rows: Int, data: Array[V], offset: Int = 0)` so I'll use that.

Get the number of rows:

```
scala> scala.io.Source.fromFile("TabDelimited.txt").getLines.size
res 0:Int = 2
```

Then get the data as an `Array[Int]`:

```
scala> scala.io.Source.fromFile("TabDelimited.txt").getLines.toArray.flatMap(_.split("\t")).map(_.toInt)
res1: Array[Int] = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)
```

Then `res0` and `res1` can be used to create a new `DenseMatrix`.

Comment: Thanks, although when reading it in the res1 was in row-major order and the constructor expects column-major.  So the constructor i used was `DenseMatrix(res1.size/res0).t`